# Show that if $f(x,t)$ and $f_x(x,t)$ are continuos on $D$ then $F'(x)=\int_c^d f_x(x,t)\mathrm dt$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to check a proof. **This is about Riemann integration**.

> Show that if $f(x,t)$ and $f_x(x,t)$ are continuos on $D$ then $F'(x)=\int_c^d f_x(x,t)\mathrm dt$

Definitions:

1. $D=\{(x,t):x\in[a,b]\land t\in [c,d]\}\subset\Bbb R^2$
2. $F(x)=\int_c^d f(x,t)\mathrm dt$, is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$
3. $f_x(x,t)=\lim_{z\to x}\frac{f(z,t)-f(x,t)}{z-x}$, is defined for all $(x,t)\in D$

We want to prove that for some $x$ and any $\epsilon_2>0$ exists $\delta_2>0$ such that

$$0<|z-x|<\delta_2\implies\left|\frac{F(z)-F(x)}{z-x}-F'(x)\right|<\epsilon_2\tag{1}$$

From the definition of $f_x(x,t)$ we can write that for some $x$ and any $\epsilon_1>0$ exists $\delta_1>0$ such that

$$0<|z-x|<\delta_1\implies\left|\frac{f(z,t)-f(x,t)}{z-x}-f_x(x,t)\right|<\epsilon_1\tag{2}$$

From the last expression we can see that

$$f_x(x,t)\in\left(\frac{f(z,t)-f(x,t)}{z-x}-\epsilon_1,\frac{f(z,t)-f(x,t)}{z-x}+\epsilon_1\right)\tag{3}$$

when $|z-x|\in(0,\delta_1)$.

Now expanding the expression RHS of the implication of $(1)$ and using expression $(3)$ we have that

$$\left|\frac{\int_c^d (f(z,t)-f(x,t))\mathrm dt}{z-x}-\int_c^d f_x(x,t)\mathrm dt\right|\le\\\le\frac1{|z-x|}\left|\int_c^d (f(z,t)-f(x,t))\mathrm dt-\int_c^d (f(z,t)-f(x,t))\mathrm dt+\int_c^d\epsilon_1|z-x|\mathrm dt\right|=\epsilon_1(d-c)$$

whenever we choose $|z-x|\in(0,\delta_1)$. I think the proof is fine but Im unsure if it can lack something. Any confirmation or review will be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your equation $(3)$ is wrong. you should write $$f_{x}(x, t) - \epsilon < \frac{f(z, t) - f(x, t)}{z - x} < f_{x}(x, t) + \epsilon$$ and result is easily proven by integrating this inequality with respect to $t$ over $[c, d]$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see but, it is not the same result what I did?

Comment: You have done reverse. You write $$\frac{f(z, t) - f(x, t)}{z - x} - \epsilon < f_{x}(x, t) < \frac{f(z, t) - f(x, t)}{z - x} + \epsilon$$

Comment: Yes @ParamanandSingh, I did the reverse but, it is not valid?

Comment: It is valid in the sense that it is correct mathematically, but it appears to suggest that $f_{x}(x, t)$ varies between these bounds, whereas your intent to show that it is constant and the expression with $z, x$ varies around this $f_{x}(x, t)$.

Comment: Right @ParamanandSingh, thank you for point it.