# A proof involving derivatives of improper integrals of the form $\int_c^\infty f(x,t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Given $F(x) = \int_c^\infty f(x,t)dt$ exists for each $x\in[a,b]$ and is continuous, $f(x,t), f_x(x,t)$ continuous on $D = [a, b] \times [c, \infty)$, show that

$$F'(x) = \int_c^\infty f_x(x,t)dt\text{,}$$

provided this integral converges uniformly.

This problem is very similar to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845468/show-that-if-fx-t-and-f-xx-t-are-continuos-on-d-then-fx-int-cd-f) except that this integral is improper. I've been able to show the the proper case using a different approach from the one in the other post but my technique required using an $\epsilon$/(width of the interval), but this approach doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence of functions $F_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, where

$$F_n(x) = \int_c^{c+n} f(x,t) \, dt$$

Since $f,f_x$ are continuous on the compact set $[a,b] \times [c,c+n]$, it follows (from the linked result) that $F_n$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and

$$F_n'(x) = \int_c^{c+n} f_x(x,t) \, dt$$

By hypothesis, $F(x) = \int_c^\infty f(x,t) \, dt$ exists for all $x \in [a,b]$ and, thus,  $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.  We are also give that the improper integral $\int_c^\infty f_x(x,t) \, dt$ is uniformly convergent for $x \in [a,b]$, which implies that $F_n'(x) \to \int_c^\infty f_x(x,t) \, dt$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$ for $x \in [a,b]$.

Now we can apply a well-known theorem (Theorem 7.17 in *Priciples of Mathematical Analyis* by Rudin)

> Consider a sequence of differentiable functions $F_n: [a,b] \to
>  \mathbb{R}$. Suppose there is a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that the
>   sequence of real numbers $(F_n(x_0))$ converges,  and the sequence of
>   derivatives $F_n'$ converges uniformly to a function $G$ on $[a,b]$. 
>   Then there exists a differentiable function $F: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$
>   such that $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ and $F_n'(x) \to G(x)= F'(x)$ as $n \to \infty$
>   for all $x \in [a,b]$

Applying this theorem, we get

$$F'(x) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n'(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_c^{c+n} f_x(x,t) \, dt= \int_c^\infty f_x(x,t) \, dt$$